# Merge two Sub-Procedures

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to merge the following two sub-procedures, into one sub-procedure. Every line I look to do so, I get an error. Any suggestions as to what's going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub URL_Classification()
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl Shift + X
Dim i As Long, an As Long, bn As Long
Dim a, b, c As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
a = Array("Facebook", "Linkedin", "Twitter", "Youtube", "Vimeo")
b = Array("RSS", "Feed", "Xml", "rdf", "atom", "syndication.axd")
Columns(5).ClearContents
For Each c In Range("d1", Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  If c <> "" Then
    an = 0: bn = 0
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      If InStr(c, a(i)) Then
        an = i
        Exit For
      End If
    Next i
    For i = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
      If InStr(c, b(i)) Then
        bn = 1
        Exit For
      End If
    Next i
    If an = 0 And bn = 0 Then
      c.Offset(, 1) = "General"
    ElseIf an <> 0 And bn = 0 Then
      c.Offset(, 1) = a(an)
    ElseIf an = 0 And bn <> 0 Then
      c.Offset(, 1) = b(bn)
    ElseIf an <> 0 And bn <> 0 Then
      c.Offset(, 1) = a(an)
    End If
  End If
  Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlNo
End Sub
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Also, this isn't necessarily important, but is there any method of removing the empty row that always appears when 'RemoveDuplicates' is executed?

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Sheets("Work").Select
    Range("D1300").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$1300").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 _
    ), Header:=xlNo
    End Sub
```

Comment: *I'm looking to merge the following two sub-procedures, into one sub-procedure.*  **For what purpose?** Can't you just call the one from the other, as you're currently doing? What do you expect to gain (aside from code that's harder to read/debug)?

Comment: within the `URL_Classification` -- you need to do `Call RemoveDuplicates` or simply `RemoveDuplicates` **instead** of `Sub RemoveDuplicates()`

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for the reply. I'm looking to automate some of the work our team does. We use the following two sub-procedures to complete our work at the end of each day. To simplify things, I want to be able to assign a shortcut key to execute both these sub-procedures.

Comment: OK, well then the solution is as @eventHandler indicates, below (and I mention in the comments, above).  You should implement that solution and mark eventHandler's response as accepted/correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Should this RemoveDuplicates be placed between 'End if' and 'Next c'

Comment: How would I know when you want to perform that operation? That's up to you. There is no objectively right or wrong place to put it....

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, by where to place it I meant, where won't it cause a 'compile error'.

Comment: Edit. I figured out how to call a module. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub has two `End Sub` statements in it.  In VBA, you cannot have an `End Sub` without a preceding `Sub`.  Use `Exit Sub` if you want to leave the subroutine before reaching the end.

Comment: It actually looks like their tring to define a `sub` inside the definition of the first `sub`

Comment: @Telestia Ah, you're right. Either way, you can't do that.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem alright. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot hav a sub defined inside another sub. maybe you want to `call` one sub from the other, in that way you make the `call` or copy-paste the code inside the sub you don't need.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I've very little coding experience, and I was just wondering in what section of the Sub should 'call' be placed?

Between the 'EndIf' and 'Next C'?

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, by where to place it I meant, where won't it cause a 'compile error'.

Comment: Edit. I figured out how to call a module. Thanks for the help.